# Gutenberg installation error try to on macbook pro

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

I am new at Gutenberg, recently I am trying to install Gutenberg in my macbook pro.First of all, I was update npm and node version. write this commend in my terminal "npx create-guten-block my-block". I followed (https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block).I am getting this error again and again i cant understand how to fix it.
please anyone help me.
Please check the following image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v62NH.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those new to WordPress Gutenberg block plugin development, I strongly recommend you use the official [@wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/#:%7E:text=Create%20Block%20is%20an%20officially,by%20create%2Dreact%2Dapp.) tool. The documentation walks you through creating a simple block and also is the reference for all the functions/packages you will need to work with.

Eg.

```npm
$ npx @wordpress/create-block@latest [options] [slug]
```

*As a side note, the [CGB Scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cgb-scripts) package you are attempting to use was published over 3 years ago and has [90+ open issues](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block/issues) - save yourself the hassle and use the officially supported way to create blocks.*